# PyQt5: How to use CSS style for QPainter?

Tags: python, css, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I want to use CSS style to control color/line-type/etc. in QPainter of Qt.

I found this but it does not help me. I have no idea how CSS works for color/line types, etc. in Qt.
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html

Here is my code. The statement to style does not work. Could anyone please help me to write me some CSS samples? Thanks for the help!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.style = """
                QPainter{color: green}
                QColor{color: #49759c}
                QPen{style: DashDotLine}
                QBrush{color: red}
            """
        # My question is here: How to write style correctly?

        self.setStyleSheet(self.style)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Colours')
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawSomething(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawSomething(self, qp):
        qp.drawRect(10, 15, 90, 60)
        qp.drawLine(150, 20, 300, 60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: qss only works for QWidget, it does not work for QPainter, Qt Style Sheets support various properties, pseudo-states, and subcontrols that make it possible to customize the **look of widgets**.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you! Very sad to know the incapacity of Qt.

Comment: @LucasMeier. Why are you trying to use qss for this? All you need is a few settings in a config file.

Comment: @ekhumoro I thought it might should work.